# How can i get the Text data from a Custom List View on Mono for android

Tags: c#, listview, custom-controls, xamarin.android

I have ordered alphabetically hte list of customer on my Custom List view, but i realise that i am getting the position of the list view control but not the object. For example i have this code:

```
//Here i am delegating 
_list.ItemClick +=  ListView_ItemClick; 

//On this one i am ordering the list of customer alphabetically
customers = customers.OrderBy(c => c.CustomerName).ToList();

private void ListView_ItemClick(object sender, ItemEventArgs e)
   {
        //Toast.MakeText(this, ((TextView)(view)).Text, ToastLength.Short); 


        Customer cust = Customer.GetCustomer(e.Position + 1);  
        var intent = new Intent();
        intent.SetClass(this, typeof(CustomerDetails)); 
        intent.PutExtra("custNumber", cust.CustomerNumber);
        intent.PutExtra("nameCustomer", cust.CustomerName);
        intent.PutExtra("customerAdress", cust.Adress);
        intent.PutExtra("customerCreditLimit", cust.CreditLimit);
        intent.PutExtra("contactName", cust.ContactInformation.ContactName);
        intent.PutExtra("contactPhoneNumber", cust.ContactInformation.TelephoneNumber);
        intent.PutExtra("contactMail", cust.ContactInformation.Mail);
        intent.AddFlags(ActivityFlags.NewTask);  
        StartActivity(intent);  
   }
```

So i want to know how can i get the object to find the specific customer that i want to show on the next page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's tough to say for sure without seeing the rest of what you're doing, but it looks like you could just use the position to pull the customer out of the list:

```
var customer = customers[e.Position];
```